# ASP.net MVC 5 Entity framework Auto generated code. How to change to Update user information?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, migration

**I have been auto generating user information for my ASP.net MVC 5 application through migrations. This information works for Register and Login, but I can only change the password when log
 into an account  . I would like to be able to update all of the user  information within the application. Previously I have only changed user information. Through the migrations process, 
but now I want to generate the view and controller in order to update my information. So how can I do this? If anybody know any answer about this, please let me know...**

Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateUserInfo()
{
    return View();

}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUserInfo(ApplicationUserManager model)
{
    var role = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        Id = model.Id,
        UserName = model.UserName
    };
    return View();
}
```

Identify Model which I changed some information.

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string userFname { get; set; }
        public string userLname { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string userContactNo { get; set; }
        public string commercialName { get; set; }
        public string commercialAddress { get; set; }
        public string commercialEmail { get; set; }
        public string userType { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
```

Register View Model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User First Name")]
    public string userFname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Last Name")]
    public string userLname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Address")]
    public string address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Contact Number")]
    public string userContactNo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Commercial Name")]
    public string commercialName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Commercial Address")]
    public string commercialAddress { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Commercial Email")]
    public string commercialEmail { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public string userType { get; set; }

}
```

I am using ManageController to change user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably have a look at this [tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97). It shows user management as well as assignment of roles to the users.

I hope you can tweak the tutorial as per your need. I am not sure if I can claim it as an answer as I've attached a link of a solution. So the credit goes to the guy who wrote this tutorial.